# Extract WAV audio file from video after uploading on web, using FFMPEG in django

Tags: python, django, video, ffmpeg

#### Problem

I am trying to find a way to extract an audio **wav** file from a **mp4** video file that is uploaded by a web user using `ffmpeg` using Django.

If I will find to extract audio, then where should I save it in my project?

1. I tried it with "Django-ffmpeg", but didn't convert and was stuck in 'pending conversion' message.
2. Then I tried with:

   ```
   import subprocess

   subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.wav')
   ```

#### Error

[image: Error]

#### Script

> def validate_file_extension(value):
>       import os
>       from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
>       ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfVH.png)  # [0] returns path+filename
>       filename = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJfVH.png)  # [0] returns path+filename
>       valid_extensions = ['.mp4']
>       if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
>           raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extension.')
>       else:
>           import subprocess
>           subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.wav')

Comment: use the full path to the executable

Comment: @szatmary please if you guide step by step how to use ffmpeg command for variable filename that is uploaded by web user in mp4 format and we want to extract wav audio file from that.

Comment: @szatmary using "inFile = videofile
            outFile = videofile[:-3] + "wav"
            cmd = "ffmpeg -i {} {}".format(inFile, outFile)
            os.popen(cmd)" it give an error  "'FieldFile' object is not subscriptable".Have you any idea?

Comment: The error related to this line of code "outFile = videofile[:-3] + "wav" ".

Comment: I just replace "outFile = videofile[:-3] + "wav" " with this  "outFile = os.path.splitext(value.name)[0] + '.wav' " error is solved.

Comment: Since you found a solution you are encouraged to provide it as an answer instead of just a comment. You can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
 - you can extract wav audio file in this way in Django:

```
def extract_audio(videofile,channels=1, rate=16000):

    your_media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    path_to_user_folder = your_media_root + videofile.name

    inFile = path_to_user_folder

    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.wav', delete=False)
    command = ["ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", inFile,
           "-ac", str(channels), "-ar", str(rate),
           "-loglevel", "error", temp.name]
    subprocess.check_output(command)
    print(temp.name)
    return temp.name
```

- secondly use "import tempfile" library to store extracted file temporary.